# YII framework access environmental variables

Tags: laravel, yii

In Laravel project we can create a file .env and store username and password as

**.env file**

```
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

And in database **config/database.php**

I can use it as

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

How to do the same in YII framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel makes use of the PHP dotenv package - you can add it to Yii with Composer:

https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Note that `env()` is specific to Laravel, you'll need to use `getenv()` in Yii.